# Java generics question

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to write a method that could create instances of any specified type?

I think java generics should help, so it might be something like this:

```
    public <U> U getObject(Class klass){
        //...
    }
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 public <U> U genericFactory(Constructor<U> classConstructor, Object..args)
  throws
   InstantiationException,
   IllegalAccessException,
   IllegalArgumentException,
   InvocationTargetException {
     return classConstructor.newInstance(args);
 }
```

You can get a constructor from a `Class<U>` object via the `getConstructors` method.  Via the constructor itself you can get information about the arguments, so there needs to be some extra code outside this factory to fill in the arguments appropriately.

Obviously, this is just as ugly as Peter's answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
public <U> U getObject(Class<U> klass) 
    throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
    return klass.newInstance();
}
```

There are few `problems' with this method though:

- class must have constructor with no arguments
- if constructor throws any checked exception, **it will be propagated** even though your `getObject` method doesn't declare it in `throws` part.

See [Class.newInstance()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) documentation for details.

Comment: The Class class was implemented with Generics, so there really is no need to wrap its own Generic `newInstance()` in another method.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just filled 'template' from question.

Comment: Those are not problems; it is what it is.  You have given the precise answer to the question.  Add overloaded method getObject(Class<U> clazz, Object...args) and it is done.

Answer (score 8):

I strongly suggest using a factory interface if at all possible, rather than abusing reflection.

```
public interface MyFactory<T> {
     T newInstance();
}
```

Comment: I agree that abusing reflection is undesirable, but with this solution you have another class for every class that a design needs manufactured or you have to have a member of a class before you ever manufacture others, since interface methods can't be static.

Comment: You can do it with a short anonymous inner class (perhaps assigned to a static final field, but because object creation is so fast that may even be a pessimisation. Having said that, the Java syntax does suck and JREs don't tend to be very memory efficient at handling many classes.

Comment: @Tom, could you please explain this in more detail?