# Java Generics Question

Tags: java, generics

I have a class

```
public abstract class FakeClass<T extends MyClass> {
    protected HashMap<Character, T> myMap;

    private void myMethod(){
        myMap.put('c', /*???? I need to instatiate something of type T here.*/)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can't figure out how to instantiate something of type T. Is this possible? If so can someone point me in the right direction to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the code for "MyClass" so we can help you.

Comment: @Mr. MacGyver That probably isn't going to help because `MyClass` isn't always going to match `T extends MyClass`. What would be helpful is some context as to what that map is going to be used for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can only be done by passing some information about T to `myMethod()`. One approach, described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448534/java-generics-question), is to pass a factory object for `T`. A special case of this, described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187109/instance-of-type-generic), is to pass a `Class<T> type` argument to `myMethod()`, which can then use `type.newInstance()` to create a new T object using the default constructor. (This will fail if T does not have a default constructor.) The `Class` object serves as the factory object for `T`.

The reason we need all this is due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in Java.

Comment: It is so unfortunate that Java generics were designed/implemented like this.

Comment: How does type erasure play into this? I'd say the reason we need all this is that constructors don't get inherited in the same way that other methods are.

Comment: @trutheality If there was no type erasure, the JVM(rather than just the Java compiler) would know what T really is, so "new T()" would be meaningful.

Comment: @luiscubal: Generics have very little to do with this. You'd have the same problem without generics (and the same solution) if you wanted to create an "instance" of an interface.

Comment: @luiscubal: Calling `new T()` is a compiler error if `T` is a class with a private default constructor. So `new T()` should be illegal no matter how you twist it. Unless you resolve all the types at compile-time a-la C++ templates.

Comment: @trutheality - In C#, there is no type erasure, so (with some extra tricks such as explicitly indicating that T must have a public default constructor) "new T()" is valid. So, if it wasn't for type erasure, it would be trivial to add support for this in Java.

Comment: @luiscubal The problem is the "explicitly indicating that T must have a public default constructor" part. Not type erasure.

Comment: @trutheality - I agree that no type erasure is a necessary but not sufficient condition for "new T()" to be valid, if that's what you meant. It is "necessary" because even if T had a default constructor, it's meaningless if the JVM doesn't know what T is to begin with.

Comment: @luiscubal let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1788/discussion-between-trutheality-and-luiscubal)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the point of generics is to be able to accept an unknown-at-compile-time type as input.

You can't instantiate an unknown class (because it might not have a visible constructor).
If you just need a placeholder to put into the map, you can put a `null` value.

Without knowing more context, there isn't much more that anyone can do.